# Pass variables in Feature file

Tags: ruby, cucumber, nokogiri, pdf-reader

I have a letter to be validated for the content in it.
It looks like

```
Sender Name                                       LetterSendDate mm/dd/yy
Sender Address
1-XXX-XXX-XXXX

                                                        ActNum:XXXXXXXXX  
Dear Customer,                                        
              blah blah...... call us at 1-XXX-XXX-XXXX, Monday through Friday, from 8:00 a.m. to 9:00 p.m. Eastern Time 
Sincerely,
SenderName.
```

I have a scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Validate verbiage of the letter 
Given I have read the PDF file of the letter
When I extract the text from PDF and validate "<StaticText>"
Then I validate the Dynamic Text "<xmlTags>"

Examples:
|StaticText|                                                                       |xmlTags|
|1-XXX-XXX-XXXX|                                                                   |RTLtr_LetterSendDate|
|1-XXX-XXX-XXXX, Monday through Friday, from 8:00 a.m. to 9:00 p.m. Eastern Time|  |RTLtr_ACCT          |
```

xmlTags value is extracted from XML file and that value is looked up in the Extracted text.

I tried the above given example and it worked. But I want to validate the letter content in the sequence it is in.

for example I want to do this:
    Sender Name                                   
    Sender Address
    1-XXX-XXX-XXXX

```
                                               ActNum:<RTLtr_AcctNum>  
Dear <RTLtr_Customer>,                                        
              blah blah...... call us at 1-XXX-XXX-XXXX, Monday through Friday, from 8:00 a.m. to 9:00 p.m. Eastern Time 
Sincerely,
SenderName.
```

Where `RTLtr_LetterSendDate`, RTLtr_Customer and `RTLtr_ACCT` are the variables and the values of them will be extracted from XML file.

Comment: "xmlTag"? That's not in your example. It is a typo? What you want to do is a simple search/replace, usually done using `sub`. What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Why is this a Nokogiri question?

Comment: It is a typo. I updated the question for the questions asked.